# How to change the black transparent backdrop of a .NET MAUI Community Toolkit Popup?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

when calling a `Popup`-Element from the `.NET MAUI Community Toolkit` with the `.ShowPopup()` method, the View is presented in front of a black transparent backdrop. How can I change the color of said backdrop (preferable to clear transparent)?

As far as I can tell, there are no properties of the Popup-Element itself that allows me this kind of change. My best guess is, that this behavior is controlled by iOS/Android platform code. If so, how can I implement this change?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Like Alexandar May suggested, you can use the Mopups plugin, it's more sophisticated and versatile than the Popups of the Community Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there should have existed a property like `BackgroundColor` of [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) so it can allow us to easily change it. However, according to [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup#properties), these properties are all related with the `Popup` rather than the backdrop area that we want to customize.

As an alternative workaround for now, you can use [Mopups](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mopups/) enabling you to create highly customizable popups inside of your .NET MAUI apps. You can easily change the color of said backdrop via `BackgroundColor`, I set it to `#F4FAFC` which is `clear transparent`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<mopups:PopupPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppPopups.MyPopupPage"
             xmlns:mopups="clr-namespace:Mopups.Pages;assembly=Mopups"
                  
             BackgroundColor="#F4FAFC"

             CloseWhenBackgroundIsClicked="True"
                  
             Title="MyPopupPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="250" HeightRequest="500" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</mopups:PopupPage>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Popups For MAUI](https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Popup-Elements do not possess a `BackgroundColor` Property. They do have a `Color` Property that, misleadingly, changes the background color of the view. Still, no way to change the dark backdrop. I will take a look at Mopups, though.

Comment: @HPe Yes the `Color`  is used to set the background color of the `Popup-Elements`, you may use the `Mopups` to achieve it.

Comment: I have not heard from you for a while. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.